# Problems with styles of multiple glossaries

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

I am working in a very large document and I want to create a Glossary, List of abbreviations/acronyms and an Index using the package glossaries-extra with bib2gls. For having a more practical example, lets assume I have the next `.tex` document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[
    stylemods={all},
    record,
    index,
    abbreviations,
    nohypertypes={index}
    ]{glossaries-extra}


\begin{filecontents}{glossary.bib}
    % Encoding: UTF-8
    @entry{duck,
        name = {duck},
        description = {a waterbird with webbed feet}
    }

    @entry{parrot,
        name = {parrot},
        description = {mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}
    }

    @entry{dummy,
        name={dummy},
        description={person who is stupid}
    }

    @entry{abnormal,
        name={abnormal},
        description={not normal}
    }

    @entry{zebra,
        name={zebra},
        description={a horse with black and white stripes}
    }
    @abbreviation{sra,
        short = {SRA},
        long = {Some Random Abbreviation}
    }

    @abbreviation{ttl,
        short = {TTL},
        long = {Time To Live}
    }

    @abbreviation{html,
        short={html},
        long={hypertext markup language}
    }

    @abbreviation{xml,
        short={xml},
        long={extensible markup language}
    }

    @abbreviation{svm,
        short={SVM},
        long={support vector machine}
    }

    @index{goose,
        plural={geese}
    }

    @index{cat,
        plural={cats}
    }

    @index{carrot,
        plural={carrots}
    }

    @index{dog,
        plural={dogs}
    }

    @index{giraffe,
        plural={giraffes}
    }

    @index{rat,
        plural={rats}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
    src={glossary},% data in glossary.bib
    sort={en-US},% sort according to 'en-US' locale
    match={entrytype={entry}},% only select@entry
    type={main}% put these entries in the 'main' glossary
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
    src={glossary},% data in abbreviations.bib
    sort={en-US},% sort according to 'en-US' locale
    match={entrytype={abbreviation}},% only select@abbreviation
    type={abbreviations},% put these in the 'abbreviations' glossary
    save-locations=false
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
src={glossary},% data in index.bib
sort={en-US},% sort according to 'en-US' locale
match={entrytype={index}},% only select@index
type={index}% put these in the 'index' glossary
]

\begin{document}

    A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}. \Gls{dummy}, \gls{abnormal} and \gls{zebra}.

    \Gls{sra}, \gls{ttl}, \gls{html}, \gls{svm} and \gls{xml}.

    \Gls{cat}, \gls{carrot}, \gls{dog}, \gls{giraffe}, \gls{rat} and \gls{goose}.

    \Gls{sra}, \gls{ttl}, \gls{html}, \gls{svm},  and \gls{xml}.

    \printunsrtglossary[style=altlistgroup]
    \printunsrtglossary[type={abbreviations}]
    \printunsrtglossary[type={index},title=Index,style=bookindex]

\end{document}
```

It produces the next output:
[image]

I have some problems:

1. In the main Glossary, although I am using the [altlistgroup style](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/altlistgroup-style.pdf), the grouping is not beeing done.
2. In the main Glossary, also I would like to have a dot in the end of the description.
3. For the abbreviations, I want them to be grouped (like in [this document](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/acronym-nodesc.pdf)). Also, I would like that the links of abbreviations in the text not to be colored.
4. In the index, also the grouping is falling despite I am using the [bookindex style](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/bookindex-makeglossaries-style.pdf).

I have spent so many time searching for a solution but I haven't found it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try to add "nostyles" option in glossaries-extra options. I am using ´bib2gls´ with ´gls-extra´ too in other document, where everything works like you want. So, instead for working out the full doc and finding it, I try to comment you what differences are between yours and mine (until any expert on gls-extra shows up ;) )
In ´bib2gls´ compilation, you have to specify "´group´" argument to obtain grouped glossaryies ... I bet you did not done that! ;) Instead of ´\printunsrtglossary[altilistgroup], try ´\setglossarystyle{altlistgroup}´. it might work for you ;)

Comment: For not colored links, I think you have to discard link coloring altogether, so in hyperref options, omit all you have and have only one option, "hidelinks"

Comment: Wow, thank you very much @TomášKruliš! I didn't know I needed to specify the ``group`` argument in the compilation of ``bib2gls`` and I was getting mad with this. I will continue researching about the link issue.

Answer (score 0):

This almost works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[
    nostyles,
    stylemods={all},
    postdot,
    record,
    index,
    abbreviations,
    nohypertypes={index}
    ]{glossaries-extra}

\setglossarystyle{long-booktabs}

\begin{filecontents}{glossary.bib}
    % Encoding: UTF-8
    @entry{duck,
        name = {duck},
        description = {a waterbird with webbed feet}
    }

    @entry{parrot,
        name = {parrot},
        description = {mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}
    }

    @entry{dummy,
        name={dummy},
        description={person who is stupid}
    }

    @entry{abnormal,
        name={abnormal},
        description={not normal}
    }

    @entry{zebra,
        name={zebra},
        description={a horse with black and white stripes}
    }
    @abbreviation{sra,
        short = {SRA},
        long = {Some Random Abbreviation}
    }

    @abbreviation{ttl,
        short = {TTL},
        long = {Time To Live}
    }

    @abbreviation{html,
        short={html},
        long={hypertext markup language}
    }

    @abbreviation{xml,
        short={xml},
        long={extensible markup language}
    }

    @abbreviation{svm,
        short={SVM},
        long={support vector machine}
    }

    @index{goose,
        plural={geese}
    }

    @index{cat,
        plural={cats}
    }

    @index{carrot,
        plural={carrots}
    }

    @index{dog,
        plural={dogs}
    }

    @index{giraffe,
        plural={giraffes}
    }

    @index{rat,
        plural={rats}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
    src={glossary},% data in glossary.bib
    sort={en-US},% sort according to 'en-US' locale
    match={entrytype={entry}},% only select@entry
    type={main}% put these entries in the 'main' glossary
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
    src={glossary},% data in abbreviations.bib
    sort={en-US},% sort according to 'en-US' locale
    match={entrytype={abbreviation}},% only select@abbreviation
    type={abbreviations},% put these in the 'abbreviations' glossary
    save-locations=false
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
src={glossary},% data in index.bib
sort={en-US},% sort according to 'en-US' locale
match={entrytype={index}},% only select@index
type={index}% put these in the 'index' glossary
]

\begin{document}

    A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}. \Gls{dummy}, \gls{abnormal} and \gls{zebra}.

    \Gls{sra}, \gls{ttl}, \gls{html}, \gls{svm} and \gls{xml}.

    \Gls{cat}, \gls{carrot}, \gls{dog}, \gls{giraffe}, \gls{rat} and \gls{goose}.

    \Gls{sra}, \gls{ttl}, \gls{html}, \gls{svm},  and \gls{xml}.

    \printunsrtglossary[style=altlistgroup]


    \printunsrtglossary[type={abbreviations}]
    \printunsrtglossary[type={index},title=Index,style=bookindex]

\end{document}
```

What style of abbreviations is it that you need?

Comment: Abbreviation style ``long`` is fine. The thing is that using the postdot option  I get dots in the lis of abbreviations too, and I would like to avoid this. Also, I will like to have blue links except in Abbreviations. This is because I use very often the abbreviations and I find it very uncomfortable having a lot of blue text in some paragraphs.

Comment: Well, I was standing in front of similar problem, but I have chosen not to have links colored in my docs in any way. I think, that in bib2gls doc are commands like \hyperbf ; that redefine the way how page numbers are printed. Maybe from those you can derive what you need ... What you see above is what I got and can do. And I dare to say that mostly only Mrs. Talbot would know how to do what you want (if it is possible).

Comment: Fine. Whatever, I appriciate very much your help. I was stuck with the problem of groups and your comments were very usefull. I think by now I will color all my links of glossaries in black with the command ``\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}``. However, I think that if I study more [this example](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/index.php?label=sample-name-font) maybe I would figure out something.